# Dúvida no armazenamento de variáveis

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos

Sou iniciante em C#, e estou tentando guardar os valores digitados em uma `toolbox` dentro da propriedade de uma `Classe`, porém o código não compila.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

**Formulário:**

```
namespace ProgramPrestServico
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form

    {


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }




        private void botaoCadastro_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string nomeDigitado = textoNome.Text;
            string telDigitado = textoTel.Text;
            string endDigitado = textoEnd.Text;

            Cliente cliente = new Cliente(nomeDigitado,telDigitado,endDigitado);

            MessageBox.Show("Cadastro de " + Nome + " realizado com sucesso! Confirme os dados. tel: " + Tel + " End: " + End);
        }

    }
}
```

**Classe cliente**

```
    namespace ProgramPrestServico

    public class Cliente
    {
        public Cliente(string nome, string tel, string end)
        {
            this.Nome = nome;
            this.Tel = tel;
            this.End = end;
        }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Tel { get; set; }
        public string End { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Qual a mensagem que o compilador retorna?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código da `MessageBox` não faz sentido. Não existem variáveis `Nome`, `Tel` e `End`.

As variáveis são **`nomeDigitado`**, **`telDigitado`** e **`endDigitado`**.

O código deveria ser

```
MessageBox.Show("Cadastro de " + nomeDigitado + " realizado com sucesso! Confirme os dados. tel: " + telDigitado + " End: " + endDigitado);
```

Se você quiser as propriedades de `Cliente`, deve ser assim

```
MessageBox.Show("Cadastro de " + cliente.Nome + " realizado com sucesso! Confirme os dados. tel: " + cliente.Tel + " End: " + cliente.End);
```

Comment: Ele talvez queira usar o atributos da classe Cliente: cliente.Nome, cliente.Tel ....

Comment: Agora sim entendi. Eu estava esquecendo de referenciar a classe cliente. Muito obrigado

Comment: @ramaral Obrigado, eu não tinha percebido.